# How can I make a float left and right text in one line using ASCII?

Tags: printer, code, ascii, hexadecimal

I'm trying to put a text in one line in an aligned left and right on both ends. Please see example image of what I meant:

[image]

Does anyone know the ascii code to do this?

All I know is this is the ascii for left align:

```
'\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x30', // left align
```

Then for right align:

```
'\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x32', // right align
```

I tried putting the text in one line using these ascii like this but it didn't work, instead it made the whole text aligned right:

```
'\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x30' + 'Text left' + '\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x32' + 'Text right',
```

By the way, I'm trying to print on my thermal printer for printing receipts using this package: [http://qz.io/download](https://qz.io/download). I can now print the receipt. Just wanted to format the products in that way. Windows is the OS.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What **version** and **build** of Windows you running?

Comment: Windows 11 Pro ver. 21H2 build 22000.318

Comment: Piping ASCII commands to a printer port have nothing to do with Windows or the version number it is running.  It is a little odd that you show a mac screen shot though.. ;)  As @harrymc is pointing out in his answer, you need to review the manual and look at the codes therein.  Yes, I am an expert.. I have written over 180 print drivers using PCL, PS, and ASCII.

Comment: Oh, one other tip.  How I myself would go about this (new printer I know very little about).. would be to create a binary file and edit the hex directly using a hex editor until you get it working.  Copy that file directly to the port and observe the result.  Once you get your file working, then you can focus on the code to produce it.  This will break your problem up into byte size chunks (pun).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I would use more recent and convenient tool to form codes that need to be send to printer instead of guessing what Windows version it is and what tools is available there, so Windows version is matter ;)

Comment: Fair enough Mr @Alex  :)  From my point of view, the tool itself *could be* part of the problem so I skip that part until I figure out basic printer function.  To each their own.  Have a great day.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Absolutely agree with you, that why +1 from me in both answers. Actually I doing absolutely the same, but filling raw file from "tool" and then manually correcting it until working, the correct "tool" again and it ready for production ;) You too have a nice holidays that are close and close !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your printer, but in general alignment codes pertain to
the whole line.

In one
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704425/165358)
it was said about one such printer:

> The command is enabled only when processed at the beginning of the line in standard mode.

Another
[printer manual](http://www.monicacolombia.com/XP-58XX-Manual-de-programacion.pdf)
says for "ESC a":

> Aligns all data in one line to the specified position.

Comment: Yes it is. '\x1B' is ESC and  '\x61' is a. I think it doesn't matter what printer it is as long as it's on ascii, it will work. https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Comment: That's exact. But only one escape code will work for a line, and some printers are particular about where in the line it can be placed.

Comment: Correct. Tested this, still didn't work: '\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x30' + 'Text 1' + '\x32' + 'Text 2' + '\x0A'

Comment: You should look at the manual of the printer. Not all printers support all the codes.

Answer (score 0):

If POS accepting direct ESC codes, then you can form control string and data using for example `PowerShell`

You can form your string as standard ESC sequence, where "`0x1B`" will be represented as [special character](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7#escape-e) and it looks like

```
 `e[
```

where The <sup>`e</sup> is the escape character and <sup>`[`</sup> is the introduction to ESC sequence.

so you can form your string as:

```
Write-Output "`e[a0LEFT`e[a2RIGHT";
```

If you want to use `HEX` codes as you posted, you need either a standard `printf` function that is available in any unix based environment such as comes with `WSL` or use `-f` [operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) of `PowerShell` which is basically shortcut to [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d%28VS.80%29.aspx) method and then you can use

```
"{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}" -f 0x1B,0x61,0x30,"Left",0x1B,0x61,0x32,"Right"
```

---

P.S.

If **POS** doesn't accept **ESC** sequences, then you can form your string as shown below. Assume you know, that maximum printer's length of line is 80, then we can do:

```
printf "%-40s%40s\n" "Left" "Right"
```

Comment: I've read here that this isn't possible on ESC/POS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68706744/javascript-esc-pos-printing-how-to-set-align-left-and-right-at-the-same-line. Resorted to another approach

Comment: @JumarJuaton You can form then your string and send it via API,  for example, if you know maximum line's length is 80, then you can prepare you string as: `printf "%-40s%40s\n" "Left" "Right"`

Answer (score 0):

So since this is in JS, and ESC/POS accepts spaces on an empty quote like this, `" "`, I then focused on doing a loop that creates spaces depending of the width of the paper minus the length of your placeholder string plus the length of the price. The width can be determined by the number of `"."` dots that fits on the paper. You can do this by trial and error, meaning of that, you will be doing a lot of test print.

So if we have:

```
Sub Total          USD
```

as the placeholder string, we just need to count it's length then add to the price (in decimal). Then, subtract from `32` (which is the width of paper/total number of dots that fits the paper) to that sum. Once you have the result, you can now create a loop that generates the spaces `" "`.

This is the function I've created.

```
function addSpaces(placeholder, value) {
    var spaces = '';
    var width = 32 - (placeholder + parseInt(value.length));
    let counter = 1;
    while (counter <= width) {
        spaces += " ";
        counter++;
    }
    return spaces;
}
```

Then I called the function like this:

```
'\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x30',
'Sub Total' + addSpaces(12, $('input[name="sub_total"]').val()) + 'USD + $('input[name="sub_total"]').val() + '\x0A'
```

where:

```
'\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x30' // left align
'\x0A' // next line
```